Why do we need implicit diff for related rates problems?
Hello  I am having to create a portfolio for my calc class. I am interested into the reason for implicit differentiation when trying to solve a related rates problem.
I am sort of trying to find a real analysis approach to implicit differ enation or just analytical reasoning using basic theorems of derivatives, limits, etc. Although I most definitely have a skewed perception of analysis as I've tried looking through baby Rudin or Spivak but they don't really go over why implicit differentiation is needed or why it's used in related rates.
I've already self studied all of calc 1-3 and linear algebra and LADR which is abstract linear algebra so an explanation using knowledge from any of these subjects could be used or even from other areas of mathematics. Thank you.

Implicit differentiation here is a fancy term for chain rule. Every variable, independent and dependent, is a function of (usually) time.

This may be an approach to consider.
In a related rates problem, by definition, one is trying to determine the relationship of rates without necessarily determining the functional dependence of those quantities with respect to the independent variable (say time).
For example, consider the volume, $V$, of a spherical object (like a balloon):
$$
V\left(r\right)=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^{3}
$$
Now, as given above, the volume is an explicit function of radius $r.$
A typical related rates problem might ask for the rate of change of volume with respect to time, when the radius is changing at a certain rate, at a given radius.
Clearly, we don't know the functional dependence of $V$ or $r$ on time, because they depend on time implicitly (i.e. $t$ is not shown in the above equation).  However, that doesn't matter, because we only care about relating the rates when we know the value of other parameters, not including the time.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}=4\pi r^{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}
$$
Given the above, I can determine the answer to the question, without ever knowing the actual explicit dependence on time of $V$ or $r.$  We are interested in $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$ when $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}=A$ and $r=B$, for some constant values $A$ and $B.$  This does not require knowing how $r$ varies with $t$ as mentioned earlier.
